# QMovie animated gif functionalty is not working on windows systems

Tags: c++, qt

I am using `QMovie` functionality in `SystemTrayIcon`. ie, rotating the gif files on the top of `TrayIcon`.

This works fine if I compile the source code on  Qt 4.7.0/Windows versions.
But the same code is not working with Qt 4.6.3 build version which deployed on the client machines. It seems **some plugins are missing**.

I used `QMovie::start()` and `QMovie::stop()` slots.

I tried copying the Qt 4.7 DLL (`QtCore4.dll`) to the Qt 4.6.3 built binaries. But this didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of things in QMovie changed with the 4.7 release, a lot of bug fixes and a few new popped up.

If you need this feature you'll need to upgrade to 4.7 or newer.

Comment: I can't see an easy one. Switching the DLLs might break some other part of the API that you are not using right now, but in the future this practice can give you a headache. An alternative is to copy the implementation of QMovie from Qt 4.7 to replace it in the sources of 4.6.3 and then recompile the library. I don't know how much work this task could be.